# persistent installerror with virtualbox

Tags: windows, windows-installer, virtual-machine, virtualbox

have an persistent issue, that i cant get off. I´m trying to install virtualbox on Windows10, and something in the system dont let me...

**From BEGIN:**

I am new in Virtual Machine. so i installed first vmware Player, to work with and then virtualbox. then i uninstalled both and have now a big *mess* to handle. cause i want to use and install only virtualbox. But the failure by install is always the same, by everything i tried.

**ERROR:**

- from setup:
  Setup Wizard ended prematurely beacause of an error. Your System has not been modified
- an extra Popup with: Installation failed! Error: An massive Error occured at installation!
- in Windows Log: 
  Das Produkt wurde durch Windows Installer installiert. Produktname: Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.26. Produktversion: 5.1.26. Produktsprache: 1033. Hersteller: Oracle Corporation. Erfolg- bzw. Fehlerstatus der Installation: 1603.

***I tried:***

Installing by turned off firewall. *Nope*

Removing all files, directories that still was on PC (even cleared all systemcaches). Restart PC and try to install. *Nope*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s not the ideal solution, but it solving the issue.

At installation, just dont need to install USB-Drivers.
and the setup is running through and completes installation.